# Permission on a symlinked directory in a Samba share

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba

I have a Samba share of my home directory set up as [described here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/share-ubuntu-home-directories-using-samba/). On my Windows box I can access the share, open files and write to them. The server I am connecting to is an Ubuntu 12.04 VM running on Virtualbox.

In my home directory I have symlinked `/var/www` to `~/www`:

```
charlesr@hicks:~$ ls -lad www
lrwxrwxrwx 1 charlesr charlesr 8 Jul 16 18:45 www -> /var/www
```

Even though the symlink is owned by me (charlesr), I cannot access it via Windows:

[image: Windows network error]

I've checked permissions on `/var/www` and that directory is part of the `www-data` group, which I am a part of:

```
charlesr@hicks:~$ ls -lad /var/www
drwxrwsr-x 3 root www-data 4096 Jul 16 18:13 /var/www

charlesr@hicks:~$ grep www-data /etc/group
www-data:x:33:charlesr
```

So what am I missing here? Why can't I access this symlinked directory that my user has permission to read and write to? I'm new to Samba so I'm hoping it's something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samba doesn't like symlinks for security reasons, and won't follow them unless you force it.  Try adding

```
wide links = yes
unix extensions = no
follow symlinks = yes
```

to your `smb.conf` [GLOBAL] section and restart Samba.  `follow symlinks` should already default to yes, but it won't hurt to set it again.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I wanted to understand what these settings meant so a bit of searching yielded this helpful page from the manual: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html

Comment: I am having the same issue, and on ubuntu server 10.10 this solves it for me, but on 12.04 the issue is persisting. My symlinks appear as unnavigable items like before I added the `wide links = yes` setting (to both the `[global]` section and `[homes]` section just to be sure). Any further ideas or places I can look to solve this?

Comment: Did you `sudo service smbd restart` after the changes?  I just tried it on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and it still works for me.

Comment: One note about this, it appears that `unix extensions = yes` HAS to be set in `[GLOBAL]`. It cannot be set only for an individual share. `wide links` and `follow symlinks` can be set only for individual shares just fine however.